# How to check in a trigger if the entire row remains the same after an update?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Of course i could do it for every column comparing like this:

```
if (old.column1 = new.column1 and old.column2 = new.column2...)
```

But it would b hard coded and hard to maintain if I add another column in the future, for example.

Is there a way to check if all the columns remain the same without checking every individual columns manually?

Comment: Can you use EXCEPT - https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/except.php

Comment: Sorry but how EXCEPT would be used in my case? I'm trying to compare the old row with the new row values, from what i know of EXCEPT it is used to compare existing rows from two queries, not  in the old/new context of a trigger...

Comment: I'm not familiar with your dbms- is there a way to select new.* except select old.*?  If the rowcount=0, no rows changed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply compare the `old` and the `new` records using `is not distinct from` which handles NULL values correctly (if all columns are defined as NOT NULL you can simply use `=` or `<>`)

```
if old is not distinct from new then 
   .... do something
end if;
```

The same can be done to check if at least one column changed:

```
if old is distinct from new then 
   .... do something
end if;
```

Comment: How are NULLs handled by these condiitions?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: good point. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thnx. I made a quick check and seems that `old=new` handles the case exactly like `old is not distinct from old`. In other words, I couldn't find a case where `old=new` gives a NULL result. I didn't expect that!

Comment: I think the difference would be with `old <> new` but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: How fast is this? Would it be faster to use hashing for comparison? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879275/1452257